# ListboxItem.Focus() throws System.NullReferenceException error

Tags: c#, focus, listboxitem

I am using below code but it's throw an error on last line

```
protected override void Append(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
{
    if (loggingEvent.Level.Name == "INFO")
    {
        FIXOUTUI ui = FIXOUTUI.GetInstance();
        Action action = () =>
        {
            ui.Listbox1.Items.Add(loggingEvent.TimeStamp.ToString("HH:mm:ss") + " " + loggingEvent.RenderedMessage);

            ui.Listbox1.SelectedItem = ui.Listbox1.Items[ui.Listbox1.Items.Count - 1];
            ui.Listbox1.UpdateLayout();

            var listBoxItem = (ListBoxItem)ui.Listbox1
                .ItemContainerGenerator
                .ContainerFromItem(ui.Listbox1.SelectedItem);
            listBoxItem.Focus(); this line throw an error
        };
        ui.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(action);
    }
}
```

> ERROR:
>   Unhandled Exception System.NullReferenceException:
>   Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>   at MyApp.Delogs.<>c__DisplayClass3.b__0()
>   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
>   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)

Answer (score 0):

try to check if you  have a `SelectedItem`   and to bypass this use the following

```
if (listBoxItem !=null)
          listBoxItem.Focus();
```